# UIPickerView delegate methods not being called even though delegate has been set after [[UIPickerView alloc] init]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

Title says it all really I have a method that is called to create the UIPickerView and in the same view controller as the delegate methods. The view controller implements the UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate protocols

```
// ViewController.m

- (void)setUpPickerView{
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
    self.groupsTextField.inputView = pickerView;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [self.pickerViewData count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return self.pickerViewData[row];
}
```

I have seen lots of answers where people say that if pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:component returns 0 this would stop the other delegate methods from been called but this is not the case for me when I set breakpoints none of the delegate methods are called at all.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: have you set delegate protocol in .h file

Comment: yep @interface StudentShareListVC : EmbeddedVC <HTTPRequestDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

Comment: Is your `self.groupTextField` initialised?

Comment: Yes its an IBOutlet I just deleted and reconnected all the outlets and the problem persists

Comment: What type has `groupsTextField` and what `inputView` is?

Comment: groupsTextField is a UITextField, inputView is a property of UITextField and is of type UIView. It is used in this case to replace the keyboard with the picker view

Comment: Your code looks correct (I even tested it). Though... maybe you never call `setUpPickerView`?

Comment: Is that possible that somewhere else in your code you are overriding the delegate for `pickerView` to be some other object than `self` (or even `nil`ing it)

Comment: Thanks for all the effort but just checked with a break point 'setUpPickerView' is definitely called I'm completely at a loss only thing I can think to do is to try re-writting big parts of the class. Its strange because it was working not sure what I did that broke it.

Comment: I am subclassing the view controller containing the code above. That shouldn't cause any problems should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help in the end I did what I thought I would have to and just deleted the text field and everything associated with it in the view controller and started again. I see no real difference in my new code to what I posted so I would assume it was something to do with the text field in IB.

Answer (score -1):

Add Picker delegate to .h file

```
  @ interface ViewController :UIViewController< UIPickerViewDataSource , UIPickerViewDelegate >
```